# How to export a 3D animation in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to visualize molecular vibrations in Mathematica and make some 3D animations using commands something like this:

```
Animate[Graphics3D[{x[t],y[t],z[t]}],{t,tmin,tmax}]
```

I couldn't find a way to export it. There are official documents for 3D graphics and 2D animations. I tried most of those filetypes but failed. If it's not possible, then a 2D gif being looked at a certain angle is acceptable. Any suggestion will help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange xunmo. There is a Mathematica StackExchange site dedicated to questions such as yours. Hope to see you there. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This just worked.

```
In[1]:= x[t_]:=Sin[t];y[t_]:=Cos[t];z[t_]:=t;
plots = Table[
ParametricPlot3D[{x[a+t], y[a+t], z[a+t]}, {t,0,2 Pi}], {a,5}]

<<<snip plots>>>

In[4]:= ListAnimate[plots]

<<<snip animation>>>

In[5]:= Export["animate.avi", plots]

Out[5]= "animate.avi"

<<<find your file in your Mathematica folder and run your exported animation>>>
```

All just mimicking the second example in
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/ImportAndExportAnimations.html

Comment: It works. Thanks. I didn't realize that example is such related to what I want.

Comment: To make it easy to find the animate.avi file, do this `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]` before the `Export` command. Now the file will be saved in the same folder that the current notebook is saved to.